# How can I call a web2py url from an outside module?

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to get the html generated by web2py from a different module, so I can turn it into a pdf file:

```
html = response.render('path/myview.html', context_dict)
```

I've included this at the top of my file:

```
sys.path.append('/home/www-data/web2py')
from gluon import *
```

However, I'm still getting:
`NameError: global name 'response' is not defined`

Maybe there's an easier way to do this I haven't thought of?

Comment: Add response = current.response. I don't know whether this is correct approach or not, but it's working for me.

Comment: `response` is an object available in the environment web2py creates when it is responding to an HTTP request -- it is not exported from gluon. You could instead run the `gluon.template.render` function, passing it the path of the template to be rendered, the path of the application's views folder (in case your template extends or includes any other views), and the context dictionary. However, this still will not work if your template (or any it extends/includes) includes references to any other web2py globals (e.g., HTML helpers, etc.).

Comment: Alternatively, you could run your external module in the context of your web2py application (which will give it access to all the web2py environment objects), or you could build a web2py environment and include it in the context passed to `render`. It depends on what you are trying to do, so hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the help once again. I've moved my external module into the modules folder (it is to be called by a cron, for now I'm trying to run it from the command line). I'm unable to get it to recognize these web2py env variables, like "current.response". Is this because it is not being called from a controller? Basically, I don't know how to run this module in the context of my web2py application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute web2py templates using the `gluon.template.render` function, but if the template was designed to be executed within a web2py application, it may include references to some web2py environment objects (e.g., HTML helper objects, the `T` translation object, the `request` and `response` objects, etc.), which would not be available when calling the `render` function outside of a web2py HTTP request.

If proper execution of the template requires a web2py environment, you can build one using the `gluon.shell.env` function:

```
    import os
    import gluon.shell

    context_dict = {...} # The context to be passed to the template.

    app = 'myapp'
    app_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(gluon.shell.__file__)),
                            '..', '..', 'applications', app)
    w2p_env = gluon.shell.env(app, dir=app_path, import_models=True)
    context_dict.update(**w2p_env) # Update context with web2py environment objects.
    response = w2p_env['response']
    html = response.render(os.path.join(app_path, 'views', 'mycontroller', 'myview.html'),
                           context=context_dict)
```

`gluon.shell.env` returns a dictionary containing all the web2py execution environment objects. If `import_models=True`, as in the code above, it will also execute the application's models (and therefore, any objects defined in the models will also be included in the returned dictionary).

By updating `context_dict` with the full web2py execution environment, we ensure that any web2py objects referenced in the template (and any templates it extends or includes) will be available.

The `w2p_env` environment also includes a `response` object, so we can use the `response.render` method to render the template. Alternatively, as noted above, we could have used the `gluon.template.render` function.

An alternative approach is to simply run your Python script in the environment of your web2py application:

```
python web2py.py -S myapp -M -R '/path/to/myscript.py'
```

With this approach, myscript.py can make reference to any web2py environment objects that would be available from within the application code (no need to import anything or explicitly build a web2py environment).

Also, note that you can exclude the `-M` if you don't need the application's models to be run.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding my python script into the web2py "modules" folder. After doing this I had to modify my import statements that referenced the other files in the "modules" directory:

`from applications.myapp.modules.mymodule import mystuff
from gluon import *`

`html = current.response.render('myview.html', context_dict)`

Then to run it from the command line I used:

`python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -S myapp -R 'path/to/myscript.py'` As described by Anthony

I plan to call this module from a cron job once it's completed. I assume the web2py cron will use the web2py environment, which won't require the same execution script I've used to test.